# Problemas com pdo erro ao criar arquivo logerro.txt

Tags: php, pdo

Notice: Undefined variable: strErro

```
   <?php
  class DB{
  private static $conn;
  static function getConn(){
      if(is_null(self::$conn)){
          self::$conn = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=sllapsocial','root','');
          self::$conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE,PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
     }

     return self::$conn;
  }
   }


   function logErros($errno){
   if(error_reporting()==0) return;

  $exec = func_get_arg(0);

   $errno = $exec->getCode();
   $errstr = $exec->getMessage();
   $errfile = $exec->getFile();
   $errline = $exec->getLine();
   $err = 'CAUGHT EXCEPTION';

  if(ini_get('log_errors')) error_log(sprintf("PHP %s: %s in %s on line     %d",$err,$errstr,$errfile,$errline));

   $strErro = 'erro:'.$err.' no arquivo: '.$errfile.' ( linha '.$errline.' ) ::     IP('.$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'].') data:'.date('d/m/y H:i:s')."\n";
   }

  $arquivo = fopen('logerro.txt','a');
//Aparece aqui Notice: Undefined variable: strErro estou fazendo corréto?
    fwrite($arquivo,$strErro);
    fclose($arquivo);

   set_error_handler('logErros');
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O problema é o [escopo da váriavel](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/language.variables.scope.php) `$strErro` ela foi definida dentro da função e não pode ser acessada fora dela.

```
   function logErros($errno){
      //código omitido ...

      if(ini_get('log_errors')) //if em uma linha...
         error_log(sprintf("PHP %s: %s in %s on line     %d",$err,$errstr,$errfile,$errline));

      $strErro = 'erro:'.$err.' no arquivo: '.$errfile.' ( linha '.$errline.' ) ::     IP('.$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'].') data:'.date('d/m/y H:i:s')."\n";
   } //<---- fim da função $strErro não pode ser acessada depois dessa linha.

   //código fora da função....  
   $arquivo = fopen('logerro.txt','a');
   fwrite($arquivo,$strErro);
```

A solução mais simples é dar um `return $strErro` no final função. A chamada nova seria feita dassa forma:

```
$msg = logErros($errno); 
if($msg){
   fwrite($arquivo, $msg);
   fclose($arquivo);
}
```

Comment: Colocou o `return $strErro` no final de `logErros()` ?

Comment: Incrível como uma simples indentação CORRETA joga o erro aos olhos.

Comment: @PapaCharlie, pois é primeiro achei o if não era excutado depois vi que era um if de uma linha só =\

Comment: Pois é, aquele `}` após `$strErro` é tenso, mata qualquer lógica - você pensa que é uma coisa mas é outra. O código tem "indentação inversa" oO

Comment: O PDO não tem relação com isso. O problema é que você tem **N³** erros, e quando arruma um, aparece seguinte, e depois outro...

Comment: Use [file_put_contents](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.file-put-contents.php)